# How can I prove this generalized eigenvalue inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$ are positive definite matrices with dimension $N\times N$

I am asking How can I prove this inequality ?

$\frac{\mathrm{x}^T\mathrm{A}\mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{x}^T\mathrm{B}\mathrm{x}}\le\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(\mathrm{B}^{-1}\mathrm{A})$

where $\mathrm{x}$ is $N \times 1$ vector

Comment: **Hint:** If $x$ happens to be an eigenvector of $B^{-1}A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then 
$$\frac{x^TAx}{x^TBx}=\lambda\cdot \frac{x^TAx}{x^TB\lambda x}=\lambda\cdot \frac{x^TAx}{x^TBB^{-1}Ax}=\lambda\frac{x^TAx}{x^TAx}=\lambda$$

Comment: Thank you @HagenvonEitzen this completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a formal proof, given $B$ is positive definite, $S := B^{1/2}$ is well defined. Write
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^T Ax}{x^T B x} = \frac{(Sx)^TS^{-1}AS^{-1}(Sx)}{(Sx)^T(Sx)} \leq \lambda_\text{max}(S^{-1}AS^{-1}) = \lambda_\text{max}(S^{-2}A) = 
\lambda_\text{max}(B^{-1}A).
\end{align*}
For the inequality part, we used the result that for any symmetric matrix $M$, 
$$\lambda_\text{max}(M) = \sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{x^T M x}{x^T x}.$$